# Light Switch controls nothing

Tags: electrical, wiring

We bought a condo in south Florida that has two bedrooms. Each bedroom has two wall switches, one switch controls the ceiling fan and the other one doesn’t control anything that I can find. Checked each outlet top and bottom no luck. Pulled the switch and both wires going to the switch are hot. Is switch just a wire nut?

Comment: So that is why my lights on the third floor come on by themselves.  Do the fans have lights?  Do the lights come on with the fan?  One wire on a switch should be be switched hot with the switch on only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a clear, focused, well lit picture of the wiring in this switch box. Turn off the breaker, pull the switches out of the box, _do NOT_ disconnect and wires, get us good pics showing the wiring on the switches and and the wiring leading back into the box and how they combine into cables.

Answer (score 7):

If the second switch doesn't control one of the outlets in the room, it's likely that it's run to the ceiling fan box, in order to provide separate control of the fan and an associated light kit.

Before the advent of cheap remote controls for fans, it was really nice to have a three-speed fan control in the wall box, and a dimmer for the fan light in bedrooms.

This is *especially* likely if you look in the switch box and one of the wires out of the switches is black, and the second one is red - and runs into the same cable.

Comment: I would expect one siod of the switch to be not-live, but it could still show live depending on how you measure it.

Answer (score 2):

Both wires to the switch live:

This could be one or more of the receptacles originally had the tab removed in order to be half-switched and was replaced with a new receptacle wired the same way but without removing the tab.

What wires go to the receptacles?